# irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk trigger command php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk, and i need to trigger command by text.

Here is the sample of code:

```
    $telegram = new Api($key);
    $commands = [
        \Startdev::class,
        \Help::class,
        \Cinema::class,
        \Theater::class,
        \Exhibition::class,
        \Holidays::class,
        \Sport::class
    ];

    $telegram->addCommands($commands);
    $commandsHandler= $telegram->commandsHandler(true);

    $updates = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates();

    if (!empty($updates)){

        if ($updates->isType('callback_query')) {

            $query = $updates->getCallbackQuery();
            $data  = $query->getData();

           //$data - here is my command (for example - "cinema")

            $telegram->answerCallbackQuery([
                'callback_query_id' => $query->getId()
            ]);

            try{
                $telegram->triggerCommand($data,$commandsHandler);
            }  catch (Exception $e){
                $this->log($e->getMessage());
            } 

        }
    }
```

Nothing happend. But handler of command `/cinema` perfectly works.

Can you help me or give some advice what can be a problem of it?

Some more info:
`irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk: master-dev` version.

Comment: I have same problem. when message is type of a `callback_query` whenever call `triggerCommand` and send Update  as second argument to it , I got this error :

`Call to a member function getText() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function getText() on null at D:\\wamp\\www\\botshop\\vendor\\irazasyed\\telegram-bot-sdk\\src\\Api.php:1369)`

Comment: @sean,I think you know the solution,right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant answer why `triggerCommand` doesnt work, but this sample of code work perfectly.

```
$commands = [...];
$telegram->addCommands($commands);
$commandsHandler = $telegram->commandsHandler(true);
//$command = "yourCommand" for example, $arguments = array of something
$res = $telegram->getCommandBus()->execute($command, $arguments, $commandsHandler);
```

Hope it'll be useful for someone like me =)